# jquery add <br> after click enter in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append a `br` tag after a user click enter in a textarea field.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
if (e.keyCode == 13)
{
   $('.myTextarea').replace('\n', "<br />");       
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Line in Textarea to be converted to <br/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999792/new-line-in-textarea-to-be-converted-to-br)

Answer (score 0):

You should get value in the textarea. See the val document http://api.jquery.com/val/.

Try this,

```
if (e.keyCode == 13)
{
    $('.myTextarea').val(function(i, v) {
        return v.replace('\n', '<br/>');
    }
}
```